# Encrypt folder with WebStorm projects

Tags: arch-linux, encryption

I have folder with projects in WebStorm.

```
folder/
    project1/
    project2/
```

I need to encrypt `folder` to read & write unavailable.

Everytime I open the WebStorm it'd need to enter the user password.

I use Arch Linux.

Can you help me with that?

Thanks for any help or any hint!

Answer (score 0):

For a similar use-case I use **encfs**. It's not perfect but for my thread-model is just fine

```
sudo pacman -S --noconfirm encfs
```

The idea is to encrypt your folder/files and mount the de-crypted version in an empty folder. EncFS runs in userspace and as long as it is running (mounted in filesystem userspace) is vulnerable to possible attacks.

here is a full example

```bsh
$ mkdir -pv folder_encrypt folder_decrypt
mkdir: created directory 'folder_encrypt'
mkdir: created directory 'folder_decrypt'
```

```bsh
$ encfs $(pwd)/folder_encrypt $(pwd)/folder_decrypt
Creating new encrypted volume.
Please choose from one of the following options:
 enter "x" for expert configuration mode,
 enter "p" for pre-configured paranoia mode,
 anything else, or an empty line will select standard mode.
?>

Standard configuration selected.

Configuration finished.  The filesystem to be created has
the following properties:
Filesystem cipher: "ssl/aes", version 3:0:2
Filename encoding: "nameio/block", version 4:0:2
Key Size: 192 bits
Block Size: 1024 bytes
Each file contains 8 byte header with unique IV data.
Filenames encoded using IV chaining mode.
File holes passed through to ciphertext.

Now you will need to enter a password for your filesystem.
You will need to remember this password, as there is absolutely
no recovery mechanism.  However, the password can be changed
later using encfsctl.

New Encfs Password:     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Verify Encfs Password:  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

```bsh
$ df -h | grep encfs
encfs                      2.0G  2.1M  2.0G   1% /tmp/folder_decrypt



$ cal -3 -m
     August 2019         September 2019         October 2019
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
          1  2  3  4                     1      1  2  3  4  5  6
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   7  8  9 10 11 12 13
12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15  14 15 16 17 18 19 20
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  21 22 23 24 25 26 27
26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28 29  28 29 30 31
                      30

$ cal -3 -m > folder_decrypt/cal.log

$ cat folder_decrypt/cal.log
     August 2019         September 2019         October 2019
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
          1  2  3  4                     1      1  2  3  4  5  6
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   7  8  9 10 11 12 13
12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15  14 15 16 17 18 19 20
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  21 22 23 24 25 26 27
26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28 29  28 29 30 31
                      30
```

```bsh
$ fusermount -u folder_decrypt/


$ cat folder_decrypt/cal.log
cat: folder_decrypt/cal.log: No such file or directory


$ ls -la folder_encrypt/
total 8
drwxr-x---  2 ebal ebal   80 Sep 21 15:24 .
drwxrwxrwt 23 root root  660 Sep 21 15:22 ..
-rw-r-----  1 ebal ebal  528 Sep 21 15:24 4plrKclESUwxrBjD4iJhJRaX
-rw-r-----  1 ebal ebal 1297 Sep 21 15:23 .encfs6.xml
```